# jQuery used with Radio Buttons to Determine which page to go to next

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I'm trying to use jQuery within my form.
I have radio buttons set up for customer to checkout as either a guest or to register for an account. I want the user to go directly to the shipping.php page if they select 'guest' or the 'register.php' page if they select 'register'.

Im using different functions based on which one is selected, so this should in theory work, but I'm not sure why it isn't.

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
<form id="firstCheckout" method="post" action="shipping.php"><!--Add option of going to sign in page for creating an account if register is selected-->
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Sign In</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group top-buffer col-sm-10">
                <input id="guest" type="radio" name="user" checked="checked" value="guest">
                <label for="guest">Checkout As Guest</label>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-10">
                <input id="register" type="radio" name="user" value="register">
                <label for="register">Register</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row top-buffer">
        <button type="guest_submit" class="btn btn-default">Continue</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(‘#guest’).click(function() {
            $(‘#firstCheckout’).attr(‘action’, ‘shipping.php’);
        });

        $(‘#register’).click(function() {
            $(‘#firstCheckout’).attr(‘action’, ‘register.php’);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work, I think the issue is with type of quote `‘` you are using try `'` or `"`

**Update:** My guess is your button type is wrong, I have changed it to `submit` and updated the code. If you are still facing issue then I would recommend after clicking on the radio button using Chrome Developer tools check the action of the form tag. That should help you trouble shoot this further :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#guest').click(function() {
    alert('shipping.php');
    //$(‘#firstCheckout’).attr(‘action’, ‘shipping.php’);
  });

  $('#register').click(function() {
    alert('register.php');
    //$(‘#firstCheckout’).attr(‘action’, ‘register.php’);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
  <form id="firstCheckout" method="post" action="shipping.php">
    <!--Add option of going to sign in page for creating an account if register is selected-->
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Sign In</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group top-buffer col-sm-10">
        <input id="guest" type="radio" name="user" checked="checked" value="guest">
        <label for="guest">Checkout As Guest</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-10">
        <input id="register" type="radio" name="user" value="register">
        <label for="register">Register</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row top-buffer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Continue</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't catch that until you mentioned it. I still cannot move to the next page however... I can see how the alert message pops up with a different message but is there a way to manipulate what is put in the "action" attribute? I'm trying to change the href.

Comment: Wait, I figured it out. I was missing another script tag with this link:
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"

Now the jQuery actually runs. Thank you again for your help!